# How to dynamically add Proto Members in Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Long time ago as @Marc stated in one of the [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055461/dynamic-object-serialization) that protobuf-net has no support for dynamic. Is that statement still valid? If not then can someone share an example how we can dynamically add the members in Protobuf-net.

Answer (score 0):

That is still correct. protobuf-net supports unexpected *data* via the `IExtensible` / `Extensible` API, but this is to support a different scenario. There is currently no support for having the DTO types themselves as `dynamic`. To do so would require significant work: that isn't a problem if there is a genuine problem to address (for example, the meta-programming re-work to allow for full pre-compilation, to support mobile / metro was significant work - but still happened). But in the case of `dynamic` it is not obvious to me what scenario this would usefully target.